# Calculating column size outside of the scope of the grid container

Tags: html, css

In my grid system the container that houses the grid is full browser width for all breakpoints but one: `xl`, or `1920px` and up. Above `1920px` the container has a max-width of `1920px` and is centered on the screen, so the outside gutters are different sizes, depending on the width of your viewport. Calculating column widths *inside* of this container is a breeze. If I want an element to span 6 columns, I just do this:

```css
width: calc((6 / 12 * 100%) - 24px;
```

In pseudo code, that breaks down like this:

```
width = (columns / totalColumns) - gutter;
```

Now here’s my conundrum: I’m adding an element that exists outside of the scope of the grid container but somehow need to be able to make it also adhere to the grid layout. It’s essentially an overlay, and is `position: fixed`. The overlay fills the full viewport with a semi-transparent background and has an interior element called `.Panel` (the white box in the below screenshot).

`.Panel` has two sizes for each breakpoint: `default` and `expanded`. For most breakpoints, `default` is equal to `50vw - gutter` (top example in below screenshot). Simple. No problem. Gutters have static `px` sizes for all breakpoints, so they’re super easy to work with. However, `expanded` is a bit trickier.

For the `expanded` state, the `.Panel` will have to stick to the right side of the screen and the left side of the `.Panel` has to begin at column 2. Here is an visual aid:

[image: panel layout]

Since the column widths use percentage values, I’m not entirely sure how to do the calculations in CSS alone to ensure that, no matter the size of your `1920px`-and-up viewport, the `.Panel` will start at column 2 and end at the right side of the viewport.

Any suggestions around how to pull this off?

Comment: Have you tried using the computed value within the code that you are trying to add the additional element? Since the generated DOM is global, you can traverse it outside of your grid-system. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value

Comment: One thought I had: It might be easier to put the right panel inside of the grid panel context and do the calculations to make it expand to the viewport’s right side, because I can access the viewport context with vw units. So, from inside of the grid panel context I could set the panel to something like `((11 * columnWidth) + (50vw - (11 * columnWidth)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the way I ended up pulling this off was to move my overlay into the grid container. Reason being I can’t access the scope of the grid container from outside of it (50% inside the container means something different than 50% outside of it), but I *can* access the scope of the *viewport* (viewport units) from within the grid container.

Adding this line ensures that the overlay panel starts at the correct column and extends outside of the grid container all the way to the right side of the viewport:

```css
margin-right: calc((50vw - 100% / 2) * -1);
```

Pseudo code:

```
margin-right: calc((half_viewport_width - grid_container_width / 2) * -1);
```

This just gets the width of the viewport, subtracts the width of the grid container leaving me with the gutters between the grid container and viewport boundaries. I only need the size of one gutter, so I divide by 2. Finally, we need negative margins, so I multiply by -1.

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: tomato;
}

.grid-container {
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
}

.panel {
    background-color: white;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: calc((50vw - 100% / 2) * -1);
    width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="panel">
            Panel!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```